# Flutter AppBar leading and actions buttons should have the exact same size

Tags: flutter, dart

the fist IconButton in leading and the second IconButton in actions. Have different sizes although i have explicitly specified the same sizes. (width: 56, height: 56)

this is how it looks [image: current look]

i want to rebuild this one: [image: how it should look like]

my appbar code:

```
appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        leading: Container(
          width: 56,
          height: 56,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(6),
          child: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
            highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
            splashColor: Colors.transparent,
          ),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
          ),
        ),
        title: const Text("Messages"),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: [
          Container(
            width: 56,
            height: 56,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(6),
            child: IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
              highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
              splashColor: Colors.transparent,
            ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
              color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: do you like to change size of icons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it with a custom appbar

```
return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
      body: SafeArea(
        bottom: false,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: [
                Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  child: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const SettingsPage(),
                          settings: const RouteSettings(name: "Settings"),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.menu,
                    ),
                  ),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
                    color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
                  child: Text(
                    "Messages",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 18,
                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  child: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    color: Colors.white,
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.search,
                    ),
                    // highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                    // splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                  ),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
                    color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```